# NSMangedObject attributes value missing, when using more than one context simultaneously

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using three `NSManagedObjectContext`s (moc) as A, B, C (parent, child1, child2 respectively) for my project.

- A(parent) is in private queue, only for saving after saving either of child moc saved
- B(child1) is in main queue, is used for updating UI part
- C(child2) is in private queue, is used for saving/updating data to core data from server response

Now my problem is when i am trying to load/populate a table with fetched data from core data using B, I miss attributes of entities. That means all attribute values becomes `nil`.

What I think happens is: I am saving data using context C and fetching data using B. Is it the reason for missing attributes?

Comment: @Amit89 , is C a child of B, or does *each* have A as the parent (i.e. is it C->B->A, or C->A & B->A)?

Comment: And for operations on those queues (any access to a managed object or managed object context), you're using `performBlock:` and *not* `performBlockAndWait:`, right?

Comment: B and C are two separate child of A. No further inheritance exist and i am using performBlockAndWait:.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar situation where when trying to fetch from a child context would return the correct number of objects but all the properties would be nil. The culprit in my case was I had called

```
- (void)setPropertiesToFetch:(NSArray *)values
```

on my fetch request. Once I removed this line I got the properties populated. I was fetching NSManagedObjects and the documentation says:

> This value is only used if resultType is set to NSDictionaryResultType.

So I would think it should've just been ignored, but in fact it breaks stuff. Oddly though if you leave that set properties call in and execute the fetch in the root context (the context that has no parent) then everything works normally. All this was in iOS 7.1

Comment: On some versions of Core Data, that would actually crash.

Comment: thanks @singebete but i tried in some other way it is working somehow.